# printing result of 2 for loops in same line

Tags: python, web-scraping, printing-web-page

I'm fairly new to web scraping in Python; and after reading most of the tutorials on the topic online I decided to give it a shot. I finally got one site working but the output is not formatted properly.

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time


page = requests.get("https://leeweebrothers.com/our-food/lunch-boxes/#")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

for div in soup.find_all('h2'): #prints the name of the food"
    print(div.text)
for a in soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'amount'}): #prints price of the food
    print(a.text)
```

Output

[image]

I want both the name of the food to be printed side by side with the corresponding price of the food, concatenated by a "-" ... Would appreciate any help given, thanks!

Edit: After @Reblochon Masque comments below - I've run into another problem; As you can see there is a $0.00 which is a value from the inbuilt shopping cart on the website, how would i exclude this as an outlier and continue moving down the loop while ensuring that the other items in the price "move up" to correspond to the correct food?

[image: Output2]

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe zip the two results:

```
names = soup.find_all('h2')
rest = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'amount'})
for div, a in zip(names, rest):
    print('{} - {}'.format(div.text, a.text))
    # print(f"{div.text} - {a.text}")   # for python > 3.6
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Hey man would u know how to remove an outlier? I edited the original question to reflect your code

Comment: You should really ask a new question here; this is an entirely different problem than the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use `zip` function in the for loop, but we can do that this way also. This is to just to show we can do by using `indexing` the two lists.

```
names = soup.find_all('h2')
rest = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'amount'})
for index in range(len(names)):
    print('{} - {}'.format(names[index].text, rest[index].text))
```